# Ideal FPS to use

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, fps

I have a C# desktop application and I am using ffmpeg as a way to 'zip' up a load of jpegs on the client PC and upload it to my server and unzip it.

The number of jpegs to zip at any 1 time varies.  It could be tens it could be hundreds.

I use these arguments to do the compressing:

```
 -f image2 -r FPS-i  + MyPath + \img%05d.jpg -crf 23  -y -r FPS + oggOutput
```

and these arguments to uncompress:

```
-i + MySavedPath + " -qscale 1  + SaveTpPath + \img-%05d.jpg
```

The options I see I can play around with are the crf and the FPS.

When I set the fps to 10 the number of bytes created is 3630422.
If I set the FPS to 25 the number of bytes created is 147892.

If I set the FPS to say 60, the number of bytes is 70023 but the quality of the jpegs is very poor any I cannot use them.

I intend to play with these 2 options to see what works for me but in case there is a definite 'do' and 'do not' rules out there I would like to be advised.

I am using ogg file extension for the video file format as it is an open patent.

Comment: You're re-encoding twice (jpeg → theora (?) → jpeg), so the "zip" analogy is not really accurate since it implies a lossless process.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hi, thanks for taking the time to take an interest especially over the holidays. Much appreciated.  My aim is to transfer a load of jpegs from client to server in the most efficient way possible.  One way of doing that is to reduce the amount of bytes that need to be transferred. I am prepared to accept a loss of detail/quality of each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JPEGs being uploaded will always be very similar, then by using a video codec you will have the benefit of a long 'GOP' size (group of pictures). This is where the video codec encodes the first frame at a relatively high bitrate, and then encodes only the changes for the next number of frames, at a much smaller bitrate.

If the JPEGs being uploaded are all completely different, depending on how the codec is implemented, it may try to do the same thing, and end up encoding a large amount of differences at a very low bitrate, hence degrading the image quality.

Regardless of the nature of the JPEGs being uploaded, adding another transcoding stage (or two) will definitely degrade the image quality to some extent.

Regarding the question directly:
I suspect the reason the FPS is affecting the quality of the files is due to the bitrate setting. The bitrate is in bytes *per second*, not per frame. You've not specified it (it's `-b:v`), so it will be using either a default bitrate or a VBR method, it's encoding 10 frames into x bytes, your second example it's trying to compress 25 frames into the same number of bytes, and in your final example it's trying to compress 60 frames into the same number of bytes, so the quality will be necessarily very much lower.

Regards optimising your image quality for file size when using a video codec: increase the bitrate based on the quality you want and decrease the GOP (`-g`) based on the nature of the files you're uploading. Altering the FPS is a rather roundabout way of affecting those two values, so if you just leave FPS at default, and tweak these other two values, you'll have much better control.

Not directly answering your question:
You will not get the same pictures out as you put in - video compression does not allow that, regardless of how high the bitrate is. If you want any chance of that you would need to use a lossless compression scheme, and given that these are already JPEG compressed, normal data compression is probably your best bet, because anything trying to perceptually encode these files will be trying to encode all the JPEG artefacts (the 'noise') as well as the actual wanted image. It would definitely be worth trying a normal zip (gzip, bzip, 7zip, ...) file and see if that can get the file size low enough for your requirements. Alternatively try decreasing the quality of the individual files (eg. Image Magick or similar) and then zipping them up.

Comment: Hi, this is a very comprehensive answer and I thank you for it.  To give you some feedback, The images are supplied via a IP camera which is stationary so jpegs are similar.  I already decrease the quality of my images.  I am really seeing how far i can 'push' things.  I shall leave the fps at its default of 25. I shall look into what the -g does and increasing the bitrate (or lowering it). Thanks for your reply..

Comment: To optimise the quality for a given file size, the most important thing to aim for is to avoid trying to MPEG compress JPEG compression artefacts. Counter-intuitively, if you increase the image quality from the camera you may be able to push the MPEG bitrate lower, as there will be less 'noise' to encode.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Note: If you use an OGG container, you'll get Theora video by default. `libtheora` does **not** support `-crf`. This option is only useful for `libx264` and therefore doesn't do anything in your command. ffmpeg will default to some bitrate instead. You need to specify some bitrate, or a VBR method. See: [Theora and Vorbis Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide)